# Check if a column has a defined set of characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a query to check if a column contains only a string of a single character, a dash, the string UNKNOWN, N/A or XYZ (case-insensitively).

I am trying to use the query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE column_1 LIKE '%-%' OR '%#%' OR '%.%' OR '%,%';
```

But not sure how I can include 'N/A after upper case or a string of single characters. Also, when I execute the above mentioned query it throws an error `'Invalid relational operator after '%#%'`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Check the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to understand how a question should be asked. This is not a "do-it-for-me" site. Some work from you is expected, post a working query, test data and if necessary, your table design too. Explain where is your error and then you will possible have some answers.

Comment: Yaroslav - sorry If i looked like IM getting my work done through this Blog. u r mistaken. I understand that you have encountered ppl who got things done but im here to learn.I have tried on my own and then resorted to seeking help from all the knowledgeable ppl who can help me here.

Comment: Then if you are here to learn explain your problem, edit your question and post your code together with some sample data, that way you help others helping you. Don't post the code on the comments, it's hard for others to follow your question that way. Edit your question and add everything that is necessary. Also, this is not a blog and this is not a cell phone, correct spelling is expected too, [check here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165505/192104) for explanation on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect use-case for [`REGEXP_LIKE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) rather than having large number of OR operators.

Given the following table:

```
create table t1 ( str varchar2(100));

insert into t1 values (',');
insert into t1 values ('#');
insert into t1 values ('-');
insert into t1 values ('$');
insert into t1 values ('N/A');
insert into t1 values ('UNKnoWN');
insert into t1 values ('XYZ');
insert into t1 values ('abc');
insert into t1 values ('fdg');
```

The following query fulfils your requirements around specific strings:

```
select *
  from t1
 where regexp_like(str, '([-#,]|xyz|unknown|n/a)','i')
```

The `'i'` means that it performs case-insensitive matching.

Slightly more complicated is your requirement that the string contains all one character. If we add the following rows:

```
insert into t1 values ('rrrr');
insert into t1 values ('ggg');
```

Then the following query will also include these, I use [`REGEXP_COUNT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions147.htm#SQLRF20014) to ensure that the number of characters in the string that are the same as the first character match the length of the string:

```
select *
  from t1
 where regexp_like(str, '([-#,]|xyz|unknown|n/a)','i')
    or regexp_count(str, substr(str,1,1)) = length(str)
```

If you need `'N/A'`, `'XYZ` and `'UNKNOWN'` to match only if there is nothing else in the string use the `^` and `$` meta-symbols, which ensure that it matches only at the beginning and end of the string:

```
insert into t1 values ('g UNKnoWN');
```

adding one more test case

```
    select *
      from t1
     where regexp_like(str, '([-#,]|^(xyz|unknown|n/a)$)','i')
        or regexp_count(str, substr(str,1,1)) = length(str)
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/acadb/2) to demonstrate.

Regular expressions can be extremely powerful, but they come with their own limitations. I would highly recommend reading the linked documentation.

---

Your current query throws an error because it's incorrect. You need to test the column multiple times:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE column_1 LIKE '%-%' 
    OR column_1 LIKE '%#%'
```

Note that `column_1` is included twice.